# uib-modal in a component

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a modal to open in a component, but all of the examples I've found don't cover components. Here's what I have so far. I'm not getting any error messages.

**JS**

```
// angular 1.5.8

(function () {
    var app = angular.module("foo-main");

    app.component("FooAssets", {
        templateUrl: "foo-content.html",
        controllerAs: "FooModel",
        controller: ["BarService", "FormService", "$uibModal", FooController]
    });

    function FooController(BarService, FormService, $uibModal) {
        var FooModel = this;
        FooModel.bar = 1;

        FooModel.openModal = function (size) {
            FooModel.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: false,
            templateUrl: 'modal.html',
            controller: 'ModalController',
            size: size
        });

        FooModel.modalInstance.result.then(function () {

        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        }); 
    };
});
app.controller('ModalController', [ '$uibModal', 'FooModel', 'FormService', ModalController ]);

    function ModalController($uibModalInstance, FooModel, FormService) {
        var ModalController = this;
        FooModel.bar = 2;
    }
} ());
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="action-button">
    <img ng-src="foo.png" ng-click="FooModal.openSaveAsReport('md')">
    Foo
</li>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
    Test {{FooModel.bar}} // "Test 2" should be output on a modal window
</script>
```

Someone else wrote the component code, so it's all working besides the modal stuff. Also notice there's a modal controller that is separate from the component. I think I'm close, but there's something I'm just not grasping about how dependencies are passed to components/controllers.

Comment: you need a `resolve` in order to inject a new dependency into modal controller. Also should be injecting `$uibModalInstance` not `$uibModal`. Example in docs should work fine in your component controller

Comment: @charlietfl would you mind posting an answer so I can see what you mean?

Comment: you really should be able to copy example from the demos right into your component controller and modal controller. Pay attention to how they use `resolve` and how they return data back in the close method

Comment: I added `$uibModalInstance` instead of `$uibModal` like so: `controller: ["BarService", "FormService", "$uibModalInstance", FooController]` and I'm getting an 'Unknown Provider' error. Edit: also all the docs say to use `$uibModal`. Not to say you're wrong, but that the docs are not great. I don't understand how to use this in a component.